# Exchange on Office 365 - need protocol, protocolport and serveradress

Tags: exchange-server, office365

I need this for documentcapture, but I'm unable to locate this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Microsoft Support Document: [POP and IMAP settings for Outlook Office 365 for business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c)

**Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server:**

Host: `outlook.office365.com`

Port: `993`

Requires SSL (TLS): `Yes`

**Incoming Mail (POP) Server:**

Host: `outlook.office365.com`

Port: `995`

Requires SSL (TLS): `Yes`

**Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server:**

Host: `smtp.office365.com`

Port: `587`

Requires SSL (TLS): `Yes`